# Plotting pixels in JFrame Swing

Tags: java, swing, line, pixel

I know creating textfields and labels in swing. Now I want to draw a line by plotting pixels in swing, I have read all the examples on this site as well as any other sites also but I'm not getting it. I know how to do it in applets but I want to do it in swing. Please help.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

class dline{
   JFrame j;
   dline(){
      j = new JFrame("Line Draw");
      j.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      j.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
      j.setVisible(true);
   }
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
      g.drawLine(10, 25,250, 300);
   }
   public static void main(String s[]){
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
         public void run(){
            new dline();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: Read the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html).

Comment: You should use paint instead of paintComponent. paintComponent is supposed used to paint Components(eg. JButton) wheras paint is used to do custom painting.

Answer (score 4):

1. Create a class DrawingPanel which extends JPanel
2. Move your method paintComponent() in it
3. Add an instance of DrawingPanel to your Frame

From the [JDK 7 documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html):

> You can find task-oriented documentation about using JFrame in The
>   Java Tutorial, in the section [How to Make Frames](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html).

As [camickr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/131872/camickr) says: Read the [Swing tutorial on Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html).

Comment: Thanks. It worked successfully. can you explain me how's it working? And how to deal with graphics in swing?

Comment: For a hint as to why it failed, change (in the original source) from `public void paintComponent(Graphics g){` to `@Override public void paintComponent(Graphics g){` and try to compile it.